# Most pythonic way to convert one list to another list using a dictionary?

Tags: python

Is there a more efficient and/or python way to make the following list conversion using a dictionary?

```
d = {1:2, 2:3, 3:4}
e = [1 , 1, 2, 2, 3, 1]
f=[]
for l in e:
    f.append(d[l])
f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) (Efficient)

```
f = map(d.get, e)
```

For larger data set and complex manipulations use pandas

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series(e)
>>> s.map(d)
```

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
f = [d[key] for key in e]
```

### Timings

For a list of 1000 items,

***List Comprehension:*** `2.346038818359400 × 10-4`

***Map:*** `9.059906005859375 × 10-6`

Comment: Technically, map function returns a generator object, not a list, so your timing measurements make little sense

Comment: The reason map *appears* to be faster is that it doesn't actually do anything, being a lazy generator. For a fair comparison (and to get the type OP is actually looking for), wrap the `map` in `list`

Comment: @Lesiak *technically* `map` returns a `map` object, which is not a generator